# Given a Sequence ABCDEFG, what is the probability that the letters A and C , both will come after D, in all possible permutations of the sequence?

Tags: probability

I have tried the problem using permutation theory, but haven't got much success.

Comment: The question should be clarified. Do you mean that the letters A and C both come after D? Or that AC comes in a chunk like that, and after D?  By the way, usually solutions on MSE usually come with explanations, so there is no need to specify that explanation be supplied.

Comment: @user170779: Also, what do you mean by "always"?

Comment: @Andre Nicolas: Letters A and C both come after D, not necessarily in chunks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focus on the three letters A, C, and D. Among the $6$ permutations of these, $2$ have D coming before A and C, so our probability is $\frac{2}{6}$.

A simpler way is to note that any of the three letters is equally likely to be first in the group, so the probability is $\frac{1}{3}$.

**Remark:** We could also do it the hard way. There are $7!$ equally likely permutations of our $7$ letters. We now count how many have D coming before A and before C.

The set of locations reserved for our three letters can be chosen in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways. For each of these ways, there are $2$ ways to put D before A and C. And there are $4!$ ways to arrange the rest of the letters, for a total of $2\binom{7}{3}\cdot 4!$.

So our probability is $\dfrac{2\binom{7}{3}\cdot 4!}{7!}$. Simplify. After a short calculation we arrive at $\frac{1}{3}$. Note that when we reach such a simple-looking answer, we really should check whether we missed a simpler way to do the problem.

Comment: You are welcome.